# UK Visitor Visa, if a Christmas visa was refused, will it affect our future PLAB 2 visa?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

My wife and I are planning to visit London on a five-day vacation on Christmas, we are from Iraq and both of us are employed as Medical doctors and have satisfactory amount of funds in our 5 months statements and leaving our 8-month-old child with or parents.

Additionally, we are planning visit UK in early 2022 to sit PLAB 2 exam which is very important visit.

**My inquiries are as follows:**

- if the Christmas visa got refused, will it affect our 2022 visa application to sit PLAB test?
- Is it OK to submit 5 months bank statement instead of 6 months?
- In the first 2 months of bank statement, we were depositing the net amount of saving from our salary after excluding life expenditure, then in the following months, the total salary is deposited and the expenditure is withdrawn later each month, is it okay? how to clarify and explain the mismatch?
- Collectively, do we have good chances or not?

Comment: When they ask for 6 months bank statement you better provide 6 months. It does not look good when you provide statements for only 5 months starting with a large deposit. It does not show that you have a regular income and spendings.

Comment: Your chances of getting a visa for thePLAB are no better than for an ordinary visit in the eyes of the officer. Actually **it might even be worse** because it shows you have an intent to migrate to the UK. It’s not the cachet reason many think it is, particularly with when viewed from the perspective of applying for a visa.

Answer (score 2):

Let me answer your questions in reverse order

- "we were depositing the net amount of saving from our salary after excluding life expenditure, then in the following months, the total salary is deposited". This will make things harder for immigration to determine your finances. Where was the total salary being deposited to? And where were the expenses being paid from? If it was to another account, send the statements for that account. If you do this, write an explanation and make it very clear.
- "Is it OK to submit 5 months bank statement instead of 6 months?" Not sending the right statements will be suspicious. They will assume you have something to hide.
- "if the Christmas visa got refused, will it affect our 2022 visa application to sit PLAB test?" Each application will be judged on its merits. If you make an application that is refused you can always apply again, and if you fix whatever the problem was with the first application, can be approved. If you make two applications with essentially the same information either they will both be accepted, or both rejected.

Some exceptions to the last statement: 1) If you make a deceptive application it will effectively prevent you being accepted for a long time 2) If you violate the terms of your visa on the first visit you won't get a second visa. 3) Immigration may find your desire to sit the PLAB more plausible than your desire to have a vacation, especially if your finances aren't such that you could easily afford both.

Comment: we receive our salaries in cash and spend in cash as our country’s transactions are mostly cash-based